# How can I make modules work independently and constantly (if possible)?

Tags: python-3.x

I made a module that fetches some market data and does some math on it. It takes the module to do a loop under 1 second. While I am running another module that imports this module, things get 5 times slower.

I figured if I could get that module to work independently and constantly, I wouldn't run into this issue.

How do I manage to do that?

module:

```
def orderbook():
d = dict()
while 1:
        orderbookvar = client.get_orderbook_ticker(symbol=)
        klines20 = client.get_historical_klines(Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, "20 minutes 5 seconds ago UTC", "now UTC")
        d["orderbook"] = orderbookvar
        d["klines20"] = klines20
```

main:

```
import module
while 1:

    askPrice = float(module.orderbook()["orderbook"]["askPrice"])
    bidPrice = float(module.orderbook()["orderbook"]["bidPrice"])
    print(askPrice)
```

Comment: Show us your code - it is impossible to help you without this.

Comment: edited as a summary

Answer (score 0):

Probably the loops are consuming all your CPU time. Try add some delay after each iteration, or - better - try to determine any conditions for loop iterations and implement some synchronisation between them.